# tensorflow find minimum distance to real points

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Bx3 tensor, `foo` of B= batch size 3D points.  Through some fanciness or another, I get another tensor, `bar` that is of shape Bx6x3, and where each of the B 6x3 matrices corresponds to a point in `foo`.  That 6x3 matrix consists of 6 complex-valued 3D points.  What I would like to do is, for each of my B points, find the closest *real-valued* point out of the 6 in `bar` to the corresponding point in `foo`, ending up with a new Bx3 `min_bar` consisting of the closest points in `bar` to points in `foo`.

In `numpy`, I can accomplish this feat with masked arrays:

```
foo = np.array([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]])
# here bar is only Bx2x3 for simplicity, but the solution generalizes
bar = np.array([
    [[2,3,4],[1+0.1j,2+0.1j,3+0.1j]],
    [[6,5,4],[4,5,7]],
    [[1j,1j,1j],[0,0,0]],
])

#mask complex elements of bar
bar_with_masked_imag = np.ma.array(bar)
candidates = bar_with_masked_imag.imag == 0
bar_with_masked_imag.mask = ~candidates

dists = np.sum(bar_with_masked_imag**2, axis=1)
mindists = np.argmin(dists, axis=1)
foo_indices = np.arange(foo.shape[0])
min_bar = np.array(
    bar_with_masked_imag[foo_indices,mindists,:], 
    dtype=float
)

print(min_bar)
#[[2. 3. 4.]
# [4. 5. 7.]
# [0. 0. 0.]]
```

However, tensorflow doesn't have masked arrays and such.  How do I translate this into tensorflow?

Comment: What if there are no real-valued points in `bar`?

Comment: This is a valid concern.  I think that this cannot happen, and, if it does, those points are useless to me and I would want to "validate" my input to prevent such a situation..... in other words, pretend that there exists at least one point in each 6x3 set in `bar` where all the components are real.

Comment: @jdehesa To be more specific for the curious: I am actually obtaining one coordinate of `bar` as eigenvalues through `tf.linalg.eigh`, so sometimes they are complex.  However, in theory, one of the eigenvalues has a convenient geometric interpretation, and so I think that at least one of the eigenvalues will always be real.  The rest are who-knows-what.  The goal is to find that one magical eigenvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do that:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import math

def solution_tf(foo, bar):
    foo = tf.convert_to_tensor(foo)
    bar = tf.convert_to_tensor(bar)
    # Get real and imaginary parts
    bar_r = tf.cast(tf.real(bar), foo.dtype)
    bar_i = tf.imag(bar)
    # Mask of all real-valued points
    m = tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(bar_i, 0), axis=-1)
    # Distance to every corresponding point
    d = tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(tf.expand_dims(foo, 1), bar_r), axis=-1)
    # Replace distances of complex points with infinity
    d2 = tf.where(m, d, tf.fill(tf.shape(d), tf.constant(math.inf, d.dtype)))
    # Find smallest distances
    idx = tf.argmin(d2, axis=1)
    # Get points with smallest distances
    b = tf.range(tf.shape(foo, out_type=idx.dtype)[0])
    return tf.gather_nd(bar_r, tf.stack([b, idx], axis=1))

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    foo = tf.constant([
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]], dtype=tf.float32)
    bar = tf.constant([
        [[2,3,4],[1+0.1j,2+0.1j,3+0.1j]],
        [[6,5,4],[4,5,7]],
        [[1j,1j,1j],[0,0,0]]], dtype=tf.complex64)
    sol_tf = solution_tf(foo, bar)
    print(sess.run(sol_tf))
    # [[2. 3. 4.]
    #  [4. 5. 7.]
    #  [0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: tl;dr: "Replace distances of complex points with infinity."  Ah.  of course!